# WooCommerce rearrange checkout layout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some troubles with the WooCommerce checkout page.

How can I rearrange the checkout page review order section (`<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">`) before inputting billing info while leaving the checkout payment session (`<div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment">`
) after the billing info section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reorder the sequence of the templates you have to remove the hooks and then add them at desired priority.

In your case you want to show the payment template before the order review template so the code to do so would be:

```
// Remove the hooks
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );

// Adding them again with different priority
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 10 );
```

You can add this snippet to your function.php